# Cordova applications and PCI compliance

Tags: cordova, phonegap, pci-compliance

We are building a Cordova application that uses Card.io to scan the user's credit card. We are then using the the payment processor library to tokenize the credit card details before sending the resulting token to our server for processing. There is a brief moment between these two steps where the credit card number is located in a JS variable before it is passed to the payment processor library for tokenizing.

As far as I understand a similar solution that would be implemented using a native app would not have issues with PCI compliance. Does anyone know if  that would be different for a Cordova application and if we need to be concerned about PCI compliance?

Comment: Anyone knows the answer? I am in a similar situation with no answer at all.